# Sharing a COM port on LDOMs

Tags: virtualization, paravirtualization

I am new to server virtualization and partitioning.

I have a SPARC server running Solaris 10.
In that I have created four domains using LDOM each running Solaris 10.

Now I am trying to share the serial port of the host to the logical domains.

Is it possible to share the serial port of the host to the domains running on top of it?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not feasible - COM ports are not virtualised.